# Geocoding from a coordinates string

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there way to convert a coordinates string entered by a user into a google.maps.LatLng object or something similar? For example, a user might enter '24 13 12.2S 16 21 57.3E' into a text field, and I want to plot a marker at that location on a map.

I've looked at the Geocoding API but this seems to be limited to returning the nearest address only, which can be some way off from the coordinates proved. The functionality is available through the standard Google Maps interface - try the example above to see. What I want is the coordinates at the green arrow placed in the Google Map, not the marker showing the nearest address (which is what the Geocoder provides).

The reason for wanting to do this is that some of my users collect coordinates in the field using a GPS device, which they then enter into a web form on returning home. The coordinates can be in any format (DD.D, DM.M, DMS, etc) with all kinds of user-introduced idiosyncracies. Google Maps handles this very nicely, and I'd like to use the same functionality in the form. I'd like to avoid writing my own function to 'read' user-input coordinates if at all possible.

Comment: Noone is going to enter: '24 13 12.2S 16 21 57.3E' - most map API's and geolocation already work with LAT and LNG values.

Comment: Thanks Max, but trust me, we need the option to let a user enter a value like that. If you're interested check out http://www.slideshare.net/meganloftieeaton/how-to-submit-records-to-the-animal-demography-units-virtual-museums-28710898

Comment: Would this help? https://github.com/boulter/GPS-Coordinate-Parser (php) a demo here http://boulter.com/gps/ using JavaScript (see source code)

Comment: I ended up writing my own functions for this. It's been in production now for five years and seems pretty robust to the range of inputs users can make. It's available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/geo-coordinates-parser